# when i click on background notification it should open the notification in Home but now it is going to Home but not showing the notification

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am using react-native and firebase cloud messaging for sending the notification and i have setup my project with the firebase everything is working fine and i am also getting the notification, i have created customDisplayMessage function for showing the custom notification. it is showing when the app is foreground state.

i have created one util/notification.js file here i have written my code like this

```
export const notificationListener = () => {
  messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
    console.log(
      'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
      remoteMessage.notification,
    );
  });

  // Check whether an initial notification is available
  messaging()
    .getInitialNotification()
    .then(remoteMessage => {
      if (remoteMessage) {
        console.log(
          'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
          remoteMessage,
        );
      }
    });
};
```

when i click on background notification it is saying the console log statement Notification caused app to open from background state: but not showing the notification

and i am calling them in app.js file

this is my app.js code

```
const [displayMessage, setDisplayMessage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      setDisplayMessage(remoteMessage);
      CustomMessageDisplay();
      console.log('Notification clicked bro');
      console.log('Foreground Notification:', remoteMessage);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    requestUserPermission();
    notificationListener();
    getToken();
    checkApplicationPermission();
  }, []);
```

**please help me to solve this issue**